# Google maps: infowindow is not closing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

My infowindows are not closing automatically when i click on the other marker..
here the code : http://pastebin.com/PvCt2z7W 
here is the code for markers with infowindows

```
 for (var n = 0 ; n <listFavourite.length ; n++)
                    //var favouriteObject =listFavourite[n];
                       addMarker(listFavourite[n]);
                   }           
                   function addMarker(data) {
                       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                           position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lattitude, data.longitude),
                           map: map,
                           title: data.address
                       });

                       var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                           '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                           '</div>'+
                           '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+data.name+'</h2>'+
                           '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                           '<p>'+data.address+'</p>'+
                           '<p></p>'+
                           '<p>Do You Want to change search location</p>'+
                           '<input name="yes" id="yes" type="button" class="btn-common" value="Yes"/>'+
                           '</div>'+
                           '</div>';                                                   
                       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                       maxWidth: 10,
                       });              
                       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {                     
                           infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                           infowindow.open(map, marker);                       
                       });     
                   };
```

i tried all the answers here but not able to work it properly
Any suggestions or help Would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating one infowindow for each marker, have one global infowindow variable.  Then all you're doing in your marker click handler is updating the content for the marker each time.  However your code will require this to be done with a closure, otherwise you're going to get each marker having the last marker's content.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   maxWidth: 10
});

var arrMarkers = [];

function addMarker(data) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lattitude, data.longitude),
       map: map,
       title: data.address
   });

    arrMarkers.push(marker);

   var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
       '<div id="siteNotice">'+
       '</div>'+
       '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+data.name+'</h2>'+
       '<div id="bodyContent">'+
       '<p>'+data.address+'</p>'+
       '<p></p>'+
       '<p>Do You Want to change search location</p>'+
       '<input name="yes" id="yes" type="button" class="btn-common" value="Yes"/>'+
       '</div>'+
       '</div>';                                                   


    // add an event listener for this marker
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, contentString);   
}


function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) { 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infowindow.setContent(html); 
        infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    }); 
}

function clickLink(ID) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(arrMarkers[ID], 'click');
}
```

Your HTML of sidebar links might look like:

```
<a href="javascript:clickLink(0); return false;">Link 1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:clickLink(1); return false;">Link 2</a><br>
...
```

Comment: yeahh experienced it getting same address for all markers..newbie to JS can u give little more help with "closure" and how to use with my code

Comment: Is there anyway i can make windows open when i click the side bar links also ...actually i am displaying some saved results on sidebar..

Comment: What you need to do is trigger the click event on any marker.  To do this you'll need to store your markers in an array (global variable), and the sidebar links call a JS function passing an integer which represents which row of the array that corresponds to (i.e. which marker), remembering JS arrays start at 0 not 1.  I've updated my answer with more code to illustrate this

Comment: hi i am trying to implement a click event in the infowindow ..but the alert statement is not triggering...the html looks ok for me..this is the line : <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(\"infoWindow\")">

Comment: Not sure, I've never tried to call javascript from within the infowindow

Comment: hi regarding the click on the sidebar ..iam getting the list from local storage how to make them as links?

Answer (score 0):

The other option to using function closure (which basically involves using a createMarker function) is to save the content of the infowindow in a property of the marker.  It still is simplest with a single infowindow.  You haven't provided enough context in your pastebin to give you a working example that does that.

Here is an example that uses function closure to associate the infowindow content with the marker and has a single infowindow (translated from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial).

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html

[Mike Williams' description of function closure](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/closure.htm)

Here is an example that doesn't use function closure (it stores the infowindow content in a property of the marker object):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_noclosure.html

Comment: @geocodezip...tried but totally confused..here is my js file http://pastebin.com/ghRPnKpB

Comment: Thank you geocodezip for links..finally learning about closure which i am not aware before.

Comment: iam trying to implement your example in v3..displaying result on sidebar and when i click the links that particular marker will open..

Comment: I saw your pastebin.  It is not complete, I can't use it to make a working example without doing a bunch of work you have already done.  I don't understand your statement "iam trying to implement your example in v3", my example is in v3.

Comment: updated answer with a version of the tutorial page that doesn't use function closure.

Comment: ..thanks you..learned lot from your examples..yeah your example is in v3 ..the pastebin link is a one js page a part of  my project may be itz not sufficient to draw example from that.

Comment: @ geocodezip...hi i am trying to implement a click event in the infowindow ..but the alert statement is not triggering...the html looks ok for me..this is the line : <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(\"infoWindow\")">