# Google Maps API InfoBox plug-in: display only one infobox at a time

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, infobox

In order to get custom info window, I am working with the InfoBox plug-in for google maps API V3 for the first time. I have the infoboxes with google places API content opening on click. But when I click a new marker the previous info box does not close. I only want one infobox open at a time. I attempted to follow the guidance in this questions: [Google Map V3 - Allow only one infobox to be displayed at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908132/google-map-v3-allow-only-one-infobox-to-be-displayed-at-a-time) in my own code. Here is the relevant section of my code:

```
 var boxText = document.createElement("div");
 boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";


 var myOptions = {
             content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
              background: "url('') no-repeat"
              ,opacity: 0.75
              ,width: "280px"
             }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
    };

 var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
  var request =  {
      reference: place.reference
};
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(e){
    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {

      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        boxText.innerHTML = '<br><div><div style="font-size: 18px; vertical-align:top; border:2px solid; background-color:; color: #555555;"><b>&nbsp;'+place.name+'</b>';
        if (!!place.website) contentStr += '&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="'+place.website+'"><img src="img/arrow.png" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px: right:0px; height:22px; width:22px;"></img></a></div></div>';
        ib.close(); 
        ib.open(map, marker); 
      } else { 
        var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status="+status+"</h5>";
        ib.close(); 
        ib.open(map, marker); 
       }
    });

});
gmarkers.push(marker);
```

Unfortunately I still have more than one infowindow at a time. Also is there another option to style the google API info window that does not require loading another script? This is going to run on a mobile website and if there is a way to only use CSS3 that would be preferable.

Comment: Can you also show where you have declared the InfoBox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps: infowindow is not closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953332/google-maps-infowindow-is-not-closing)

Comment: Ok I have added the additional code. Not the this code is all within function createMarker(place){//code is in here}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using this example http://www.geocodezip.com/fredagsmat_se_infoboxA.html which was picked up from this forum post https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/gLHyTaKlJ2c.

If I understand correctly, you need to make your infobox variable global by placing it outside of the initialize function. In my case var ib = null;. Then you place ib = new InfoBox({}); right before the close of your initialize function. How you call the function will depend on your particular javascript but just refer to the example for some guidance.